# FirebaseVisionImage / ML Toolkit cropRect() support

Tags: firebase-mlkit

I am posting this question by request of a Firebase engineer.

I am using the Camera2 API in conjunction with Firebase-mlkit vision.  I am using both barcode and on-platform OCR.  The things I am trying to decode are mostly labels on equipment.  In testing the application I have found that trying to scan the entire camera image produces mixed results.  The main problem is that the field of view is too wide.

- If there are multiple bar codes in view, firebase returns multiple results.  You can sort of work around this by looking at the coordinates and picking the one closest to the center.
- When scanning text, it's more or less the same, except that you get multiple Blocks, many times incomplete (you'll get a couple of letters here and there).

You can't just narrow the camera mode, though - for this type of scanning, the user benefits from the "wide" camera view for alignment.  The ideal situation would be if you have a camera image (let's say for the sake of argument it's 1920x1080) but only a subset of the image is given to firebase-ml.  You can imagine a camera view that has a guide box on the screen, and you orient and zoom the item you want to scan within that box.

You can select what kind of image comes from the Camera2 API but firebase-ml spits out warnings if you choose anything other than YUV_420_488.  The problem is that there's not a great way in the Android API to deal with YUV images unless you do it yourself.  That's what I ultimately ended up doing - I solved my problem by writing a Renderscript that takes an input YUV, converts it to RGBA, crops it, then applies any rotation if necessary.  The result of this is a Bitmap, which I then feed into either the FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions or FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer.

Note that the bitmap itself cases mlkit runtime warnings, urging me to use the YUV format instead.  This is possible, but difficult.  You would have to read the byte array and stride information from the original camera2 yuv image and create your own.  The object that comes from camear2 is unfortunately a package-protected class, so you can't subclass it or create your own instance - you'd essentially have to start from scratch.  (I'm sure there's a reason Google made this class package protected but it's extremely annoying that they did).

The steps I outlined above all work, but with format warnings from mlkit.  What makes it even better is the performance gain - the barcode scanner operating on an 800x300 image takes a tiny fraction as long as it does on the full size image!

It occurs to me that none of this would be necessary if firebase paid attention to cropRect.  According to the Image API, cropRect defines what portion of the image is valid.  That property seems to be mutable, meaning you can get an Image and change its cropRect after the fact.  That sounds perfect.  I thought that I could get an Image off of the ImageReader, set cropRect to a subset of that image, and pass it to Firebase and that Firebase would ignore anything outside of cropRect.

This does not seem to be the case.  Firebase seems to ignore cropRect.  In my opinion, firebase should either support cropRect, or the documentation should explicitly state that it ignores it.

My request to the firebase-mlkit team is:

1. Define the behavior I should expect with regard to cropRect, and document it more explicitly
2. Explain at least a little about how images are processed by these recognizers.  Why is it so insistent that YUV_420_488 be used?  Maybe only the Y channel is used in decoding?  Doesn't the recognizer have to convert to RGBA internally?  If so, why does it get angry at me when I feed in Bitmaps?
3. Make these recognizers either pay attention to cropRect, or state that they don't and provide another way to tell these recognizers to work on a subset of the image, so that I can get the performance (reliability and speed) that one would expect out of having to ML correlate/transform/whatever a smaller image.

--Chris